# ajax - submit form with ajax 2

Tags: jquery

Noting happened on submit. why is that?

```
<button id="submitRegButton" class="btn btn-success">SEND</button>

$(document).on('#submitRegButton','form',function(e) {
.....
});
```

Comment: your syntax is wrong. check this docs http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong.

Try this

```
$(document).on('click','#submitRegButton',function(e) {
     alert("button click");
});
```